# Pythonanywhere - Django - No module named 'api.urls'

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, pythonanywhere

I uploaded my django project to pythonanywhere. But, I got some errors.

`No module named 'api.urls'`
 in project/urls.py

project/urls.py

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.conf.urls import include, url
from rest_framework.urlpatterns import format_suffix_patterns


urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
    url(r'^api/', include('user.urls')),
    url(r'^api/', include('api.urls')),  # Error at here
]

urlpatterns = format_suffix_patterns(urlpatterns)
```

**Only error at api.urls. But user.urls not.** I can not understand why?
"api" and "user" apps are the same root. But, "user.urls" worked correctly, "api.urls" is not.

My project structure:

```
├── project
│   ├── api
│   │   ├── __init__.py
│   │   ├── admin.py
│   │   ├── apps.py
│   │   ├── migrations
│   │   ├── models.py
│   │   ├── serializers.py
│   │   ├── tests.py
│   │   ├── urls.py
│   │   └── views.py
│   ├── manage.py
│   ├── media
│   ├── project
│   │   ├── __init__.py
│   │   ├── asgi.py
│   │   ├── settings.py
│   │   ├── urls.py
│   │   └── wsgi.py
│   └── user
│       ├── __init__.py
│       ├── admin.py
│       ├── apps.py
│       ├── migrations
│       ├── models.py
│       ├── serializers.py
│       ├── tests.py
│       ├── urls.py
│       └── views.py
└── requirements.txt
```

pythonanywhere_com_wsgi.py

```
# +++++++++++ DJANGO +++++++++++
# To use your own django app use code like this:
import os
import sys

path = '/home/setname/example/project'

if path not in sys.path:
    sys.path.append(path)

os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE'] = 'project.settings'

# then:
from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application
application = get_wsgi_application()
```

Help me,
Thanks.

Comment: Can you share your projects setting? Seems like the `api` is missing from installed apps in settings

Comment: Here. 
``` INSTALLED_APPS = [
    # My apps
    'api',
    'user',

    # Default apps of django
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'rest_framework',
]
```
help me

Comment: I added to INSTALLED_APPS. 
"user" and "api" package are the same root folder. But "user" is correct, "api" is not.

Comment: Do you have an __init__.py in your api folder?

Comment: Yep, I added it to my api folder

Comment: url(r'^user/', include('user.urls')), # change api for user
    url(r'^api/', include('api.urls')),  # Error at here

Comment: @HenryRamos it's still not working. I think It's error at 'api.urls', but i don't understand

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I resolved this problem.
In order to resolve this problem. You need use a new version of python then do pip install django